# Geocoder form with Google Maps autosuggest

Tags: javascript, jquery, geospatial, google-maps

Even though it's simple, I've spent quite a bit of time on it, learning as I go. Is there anyway I can make this code more efficient, more crossbrowser compatible or just generally better?

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/njDvn/113/)

```
<!-- Geocode -->
$(document).ready(function () {
    var GeoCoded = { done: false };
    autosuggest();
    $('#myform').on('submit', function (e) {
    if (GeoCoded.done) return true;

        e.preventDefault();
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        var address = document.getElementById('location').value;

        $('#myform input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled', true);

        geocoder.geocode({
            'address': address
        },

        function (results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                var latLng = results[0].geometry.location;
                $('#lat').val(results[0].geometry.location.lat());
                $('#lng').val(results[0].geometry.location.lng());
                GeoCoded.done = true;
                $('#myform').submit();
            } else {
                console.log("Geocode failed: " + status);
                //enable the submit button
                $('#myform input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled', false);
            }

        });

    });

});


function autosuggest() {
        var input = document.getElementById('location');
        var options = {
            types: [],
        };
        var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
    }
```

Comment: To get some quick ideas for improvements, you can try putting your code through [jslint](http://jslint.com), or [jshint](http://jshint.com) - jshint is easier to use as it requires less set-up (for your code, you mostly just need to check the "jQuery" checkbox).

Answer (score 3):

From a once over:

- When you wrote

  ```
  var latLng = results[0].geometry.location;
  $('#lat').val(results[0].geometry.location.lat());
  $('#lng').val(results[0].geometry.location.lng());
  ```

  you probably meant to write

  ```
  var latLng = results[0].geometry.location;
  $('#lat').val(latLng .lat());
  $('#lng').val(latLng .lng());
  ```
- I wonder why you capture `new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);` into `autocomplete` since you do nothing with `autocomplete`.
- 1 `var` block with comma separated variables is considered the standard, preferably on top.
- You could capture `document.getElementById('location')` into a var to prevent repeated DOM lookups
- Don't do `console.log` in production code
- Creating `GeoCoded` as an object with 1 property is overkill, why not simply
   
  `var geoCodingDone = false;`
- lowerCamelCasting is not applied consistently : `autosuggest` -> `autoSuggest`, `autocomplete` -> `autoComplete`
- There is an indentation problem after `return true;`

With all that, I would counter suggest something like

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  var geoCodingDone = false,
      locationInput = document.getElementById('location'); 

  createAutoSuggest();

  $('#myform').on('submit', function (e) {
    if (geoCodingDone) 
      return true;

    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder(),
        address  = locationInput.value;  

    e.preventDefault();

    $('#myform input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled', true);

    geocoder.geocode( {'address': address }, function (results, status){
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            var latLng = results[0].geometry.location;
            $('#lat').val(latLng.lat());
            $('#lng').val(latLng.lng());
            geoCodingDone = true;
            $('#myform').submit();
        } else {
            $('#myform input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled', false);
        }
    });
  });
});

function createAutoSuggest(){
  var options = { types: [] };
  new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(locationInput, options);
}
```